# Pressing back button resets all the variables react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have implemented a add fucntionality item, which works fine. tried using console.log it works. But as soon as i press back button and Modal closses, all of the data I have added resets to null. why?

```
const [resultJson, setResultJson] = useState({});
for (const x in teachers) {    
  resultJson[inputJson.teachers[x]] = {
    'classes':[],
    'students' : []
  };
}
```

Add call

```
<FlatList
  data={getStudents()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Pressable
      // title={item}
      onPress={() => {
        addStudents(item);
      }}
    >
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </Pressable>
  )}
/>
<Button
  title="back"
  onPress={() => {
    setSecModalVisible(!secModalVisible);
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  }}
></Button>
```

Add function

```
const addStudents = (item) => {
  if (resultJson[name].students.includes(item)) {
    console.log(resultJson);
    console.log(item + "already there");
  } else {
    console.log("adding" + item);
    resultJson[name].students.push(item);
  }
};
```

Comment: You're mutating the state, `resultJson`, and that violates the principles of `React`, which in turn can lead to odd behavior. What you should do instead is use the `setResultJson` to change the value of `resultJson`. So for example instead of `resultJson[name].students.push(item);` you should do something like this: `setResultJson((old) => ({ ...old, [name]: { students: [...old[name].students ?? [], item] } }));`

Comment: I tried this, but it is not adding anything in it. This is the result I am getting; ```{"Alice": {"classes": [], "students": []}, "Bob": {"classes": [], "students": []}, "Charlie": {"classes": [], "students": []}}```